# how to get items from a Sink in the order they were provided in Source?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a Source like this:

```
val queueP : Promise[SourceQueueWithComplete[List[String]]] = Promise()
val source = Source.queue(Constants.CHUNK_SIZE, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).mapMaterializedValue {
      q : SourceQueueWithComplete[List[String]] => {
        queueP.success(q)
        q
      }
    }.watchTermination() {
      case (_,f) => f.recoverWith {
        case t : Exception => {
          queueP.tryFailure(new Exception)
          Future.failed(t)
        }
      }
    }
```

which I provide items to:

```
queueP.future.map(f => f.offer(someList))
```

But when I Sink on the other end:

```
val sink = Sink.foreach[List[String]](someList => {
      ...
    })

    val flow = rowsSource.to(sink)
    flow.run
```

the items I receive come out of order, which kind of defeats the purpose of a queue in the first place. Is there a way to force the the items to come in the order they were offered to the queue?

Comment: are you sure `rowsSource` is the same as `source`? could you add more code to shed some more light on the issue?

Comment: @StefanoBonetti I'm sure - I guess my question is, are they supposed to come in order? My understanding is that the items can come in any order (whenever the futures complete), according to information I have found. But there must be a way to force the original order.

Comment: From your code, it looks like you only offer **one** element to your Source.queue, and that is a `List[String]`. My conclusion would be that, whenever it's received by the Sink, it will still have the elements in the same order. Or are you offering more than one element to that materialized queue?

Comment: @StefanoBonetti that is taken out of context, the offer is within a loop. I offer many lists.

Answer (score 2):

Because you `offer` your elements as part of your `mapMaterializedValue` call, you effectively need to materialize (i.e. run) your `Source.queue` every time you want to submit an element.

As a side effect, you get your elements out of order, because each and every stream materialization happens asynchronously.

A healthier approach to your problem would involve running a single graph, getting a hold a single queue, and submit multiple elements to it. See code example below:

```
val queue: SourceQueueWithComplete[List[String]] = 
  Source.queue[List[String]](Constants.CHUNK_SIZE, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
    .to(Sink.foreach { list ⇒ /* do stuff */ })
    .run()

queue.offer(List("a", "b"))  
queue.offer(List("c", "d"))
```